# In Linux, which tools are free to use to make Web site mockups?

Tags: seo, web-development

I am using Ubuntu/Fedora. Which available mock-up builders i can use before making a website?

**Follow up:**

> Adobe [AIR for Linux is no longer supported](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/408/kb408084.html). To access older,
>   unsupported versions, please read the AIR archive. Different operating
>   system?

Comment: Have you tried installing Adobe Air through the Ubuntu Software Center instead of downloading it directly from Adobe? It might come with some built-in fixes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always used GIMP (an open source alternative to photoshop). I don't have the link off hand but have seen collections of custom brushes to make the process easier.

Comment: I have been using GIMP for dacades, and now i am little bit tired and in need somethinglike Balsamiq or alternatives. Any idea?

Comment: After looking at Balsamiq I did a quick search for wireframe brushes GIMP and here's an article that has brushes to download at the end (Note I have not used these brushes). http://www.designtopx.com/2010/01/web-page-wireframe-in-seconds-gimp/ with a brush for every wireframe element it's essentially the same as Balsamiq unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3):

[Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com) runs on Linux, via Adobe Air.

Comment: Please see above screen shot.